# Can a table with no primary key lead to slowness of insert with growth of data in Informix?

Tags: informix

There is a table with no primary key column and records can be duplicated. Over time, with the growth of the table, we have noticed that inserting new records into that table is getting slower and slower. Is there any relation between that slowness and not having a `primary key`?

Comment: I think the answer is "maybe, but probably not". It depends on what the schema of the table looks like — are there any indexes on it at all, for example? You have no PRIMARY KEY clause; do you have any UNIQUE constraints? Presumably not if records can be duplicated, but not having a primary key (and hence allowing duplicate records) raises questions about whether the design of the table is sensible. However, there shouldn't be any major issues. Do you have any BYTE, TEXT, BLOB or CLOB columns? Did you set the first extent size and next extent size? Without more information, it's hard to guess.

Comment: If the table has variable length rows, for example by using varchar or lvarchar columns, then something else to consider is whether the onconfig parameter MAX_FILL_DATA_PAGES is set. When set this may require the database server to perform more checks when finding a suitable page to insert a new row. Such checks may increase the time it takes for an insert operation.